# bitcoin node take transactions fee and validate them

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, transaction-fees, full-node, nodes

a bitcoin node check transactions and validate them . does it take transaction s fee. when validate transactions how much bitcoin transaction fees for a node.and possible reduce fees in a bitcoin node

Answer (score 3):

Transaction fees are paid to the miner that includes that transaction in their block. Nodes do not earn transaction fees (or any other fees) for validating transactions.

You can reduce fees by using segwit inputs, and by waiting for periods when the mempool is relatively empty.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions fees goes to miner along with the mining rewards. Fee is a function of how much transactions are in mempool and several other things.

Using cli of bitcoin node, you can get an estimate fee as per number of blocks time you want for confirmation.

Ex - Let's say I am ok with my transaction getting confirmed after approx n blocks are formed

```
./bitcoin-cli -conf=<path_to_conf_file> estimatesmartfee n
```

This will return you approx fee value. You can then set it using another command of cli

```
./bitcoin-cli -conf=<path_to_conf_file> settxfee <fee_value>
```

You can write it an script and then run time to time to use only what you need. vary **n** to increase or decrease speed of transaction confirmations